# Resizing canvas size in fabricjs creates another canvas container

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

I'm trying to make the canvas resize when I click a button... but when I click the button it adds another "canvas-container" div outside of the canvas which messes everything up. What am I doing wrong? I'm kinda stuck.

```
    export default () => {
      const fabricCanvas = useRef(new fabric.Canvas());
      const canvasEl = useRef();
      const canvasWidth = 1200;
      const canvasHeight = 1200;

      useEffect(
    () => {
      fabricCanvas.current.initialize(canvasEl.current, {
        width: canvasWidth / 2,
        height: canvasHeight / 2,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        preserveObjectStacking: true,
      });
      fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
      fabric.Object.prototype.cornerColor = "#ff6c14";
      fabric.Object.prototype.cornerStyle = "rect";
      fabric.Object.prototype.cornerSize = "8";
      fabric.Object.prototype.borderColor = "#ff6c14";
    },
    [canvasEl.current]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
      const keycode = e.keyCode;
      if (keycode === 8 || keycode === 46) {
        const canvas = fabricCanvas.current;
        const activeObjects = canvas.getActiveObjects();
        if (activeObjects[0].isEditing) return;
        canvas.remove(...activeObjects);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const changeCanvasSize = () => {
    const canvas = fabricCanvas.current;
    canvas.setWidth(1080);
    canvas.setHeight(1920);
    canvas.calcOffset();
  };

  return (
    <div>
            <button onClick={changeCanvasSize}>
              Change Size
            </button>
          <canvas id="canvas">
            Your browser doesn't support this. You should consider upgrading.
          </canvas>
</div>
);
};
```

Here is how the output looks when i click the button:

```
<div class="canvas-container" style="width: 1080px; height: 1920px; position: relative; user-select: none;">
<div class="canvas-container" style="width: 600px; height: 600px; position: relative; user-select: none;">
<canvas id="canvas" class="lower-canvas" width="1200" height="1200" style="position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 600px; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: none; user-select: none;">Your browser doesn't support this. You should consider upgrading.</canvas>
<canvas class="upper-canvas " width="1200" height="1200" style="position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 600px; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: none; user-select: none; cursor: default;"></canvas>
</div></div>
```